# How to use XPATH to access an attribute/property of an iframe?

Tags: dom, xpath, iframe, browser, scripting

As you can see I'm not trying to access anything from inside the actual iframe's contentWindow but rather the iframe tag itself.

Example iframe element:

```
<iframe id="placeholder"
data-ids="1J2cSrn6ox4,BUQzSn85NMs,Fzav6plKfr8,MsNJTTP3LMM,hTZLXnY7Gc0"
style="100%; 330px;" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen="1"
allow="accelerometer; autoplay; encrypted-media; gyroscope;
picture-in-picture"  width="100%" height="100%"></iframe>
```

I'm trying to retrieve the string that is assigned to the property data-ids
how can I retrieve this using XPath?

```
//iframe[1].data-ids

//*[@id="placeholder"]/@data-ids
```

If I use JavaScript getAttribute function works to retrieve:

```
var frame = document.querySelector('iframe');
var val = frame.getAttribute('data-ids');
alert(val);
```

but how to do it in Xpath?

### Update 1

I'm using the inspector in Chrome, under elements, CTRL-F doing search for `XPATH;` it won't let me access the specific string I'm trying to reference:

```
//*[@id="placeholder"]//@data-ids
```

When I use this it doesn't work it still highlights the entire iframe.

Do you know how to access only the string between quotes assigned to "data-ids" attribute of the iframe tag?

Is there a command similar to the JS command `getAttribute()` in Xpath?
I want to return only "1J2cSrn6ox4,BUQzSn85NMs,Fzav6plKfr8,MsNJTTP3LMM,hTZLXnY7Gc0".

### Update 2

Now I'm now using JavaScript "snippet" inside chrome's inspector to evaluate the Xpath reference like so:

```
function getElementByXpath(path) {
  return document.evaluate(path, document, null, XPathResult.FIRST_ORDERED_NODE_TYPE, null).singleNodeValue;
}
test = getElementByXpath("//*[@id="placeholder"]//@data-ids")
console.log(test);
```

and it now outputs the following to the console:

```
data-ids="1J2cSrn6ox4,BUQzSn85NMs,Fzav6plKfr8,MsNJTTP3LMM,hTZLXnY7Gc0"
```

which is great, but how do I get *just* the text? Not the name/value pair, not the `attrName="value"` but rather just what's in between the quotes?

I'm not asking how to do it with JavaScript; I'm asking how to target the string value of the attribute *without* converting it to a string.

Answer (score 0):

Ideally `//iframe/@data-ids` should return the value.

[image]

Can you please elaborate what message you are getting and where you are trying the xpath.